# Nuxt stylelint empty line before

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, stylelint

I'm trying to setup some rules about empty lines before in stylelint in Nuxt but doesn't seems to work as expected, this is the code I'm trying to fix:

```
.header {
    header {
      background-color: $color-primary-300;
    }
    &__inner {
      box-shadow: $box-shadow;
    }
    &__spacer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 72px;

      &--small {
        height: 66px;
      }
      @include respond-to(lg) {
        height: 106px;
      }

      &--no-links {
        @include respond-to(lg) {
          height: 0;
        }
      }
```

the `&_` and `@include` declaration should have an empty line before but only if aren't nested like the last one in `&--no-links` block.

This is my configuration:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "stylelint-declaration-strict-value"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "at-rule-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        "ignoreAtRules": [
          "function",
          "if",
          "each",
          "include",
          "mixin",
          "at-root",
          "extend"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rule-empty-line-before": [
      "always-multi-line",
      {
        "except": ["first-nested"],
        "ignore": ["after-comment"]
      }
    ],
    "at-rule-empty-line-before": [
      "always",
      {
        "except": ["first-nested"]
      }
    ],
    "no-empty-source": null,
    "no-descending-specificity": null,
    "declaration-no-important": true,
    "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": [true, {
      "ignorePseudoElements": ["v-deep"]
    }]
  },
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've found the solution by installing `stylelint-config-recommended-scss`

```
"scss/dollar-variable-empty-line-before": [ "always", {
  "except": [
    "first-nested",
    "after-comment",
    "after-dollar-variable"
  ]
} ]
},
"extends": "stylelint-config-recommended-scss"
```